# TFS Unable To Viewing Work Items - TF265000 TFS error client does not support the selected query type

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

In **TFS** im currently unable to viewing **work items** in Visual Studio 2008. The **Error** is - TF265000 TFS error client does not support the selected query type when I open Team Explorer --> Expand Work Items --> Expand Team Queries and double click the item to open the list of tasks.

[image]

I thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Do you have SP1 for Visual Studio 2008 installed?

Comment: No; let me try that Thanks

Comment: Did it work? Did you check the second part of my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Install Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2008.

Then install the Compatibility GDR from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983

This allows the use of VS2008 with TFS2012.

[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce276ee3-83ef-4242-ac24-9fab90631b41/vs-2008-and-tfs-2012-compatability)